# Does solrj encode the content?

Tags: tomcat, encoding, solrj

When I add a document solr with the use of solrj is the content then encoded?

```
CommonsHttpSolrServer server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer(
            "http://localhost:8080/solr/");
SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.addField("id", 1);
doc.addField("city", "Zürich");
server.add(doc);
server.commit();
```

Because when i search for it with the following code I can not find it (other towns work).

```
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();
solrQuery.set(CommonParams.WT, "json");
solrQuery.setQuery("Zürich");

QueryResponse rsp = locationSearchServer.query(solrQuery);
return rsp.getBeans(City.class);
```

I can see in the debugger that the query parameter is encoded to UTF-8 automatically.

I have also added the UTF-8 property to tomcat http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#URI_Charset_Config but with no effect.

Do I have to add the content encoded or does solrj this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that queries by GET can fail with international characters. Normally this should be solved by the Tomcat-Param, but in my case not.

A solution which works allways is send it as POST

```
QueryResponse rsp = locationSearchServer.query(solrQuery, METHOD.POST);
```